# Organizing objects hierarchically by two levels in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I'm working on an Angular app that utilizes a [cell modifier](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#?example=cell-modifier) inside a [custom cell template](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#?example=custom-templates) in Angular Bootstrap Calendar. Inside each cell, instead of a standard event, I'm placing a set of tables that are used for signing up for shifts at a station for that day. The tables are split into two groups; am and pm, and within each am/pm group, there is a table for each station, with three rows in each table.

AM

| 1 |Position|Name  |
|   |Pos 1   |Name 1|
|   |Pos 2   |Name 2|
|   |Pos 3   |Name 3|

| 2 |Position|Name  |
|   |Pos 1   |Name 1|
|   |Pos 2   |Name 2|
|   |Pos 3   |Name 3|

PM

| 1 |Position|Name  |
|   |Pos 1   |Name 1|
|   |Pos 2   |Name 2|
|   |Pos 3   |Name 3|

| 2 |Position|Name  |
|   |Pos 1   |Name 1|
|   |Pos 2   |Name 2|
|   |Pos 3   |Name 3|

Inside of my cell modifier function, I get an array of shift objects for that day, and each shift object contains the ampm value and the station value:

```
 {
    "_id": "57776537ac0a88010063b9b9",
    "modified": "2016-07-02T06:54:47.518Z",
    "data": {
      "station": "1",
      "date": "2016-07-01T07:00:00.000Z",
      "ampm": "pm",
      "slots": [
        {
          "position": "AO",
          "name": ""
        },
        {
          "position": "FF",
          "name": {
            "_id": "57776507ac0a88010063b9b8",
            "modified": "2016-07-02T06:53:59.661Z",
            "data": {
              "group": "suppression",
              "driving": {
                "n": false,
                "d": true,
                "ao": false,
                "wt": false
              },
              "emtLevel": "b",
              "secondaryPhoneNumber": "",
              "primaryPhoneNumber": "5556781234",
              "emailAddress": "person.one@mysite.com",
              "fullName": "Person One",
              "userName": "person.one",
              "assignedStation": "18",
              "probationary": false
            },
            "form": "57427ba554ec330100dad645",
            "created": "2016-07-02T06:53:59.644Z",
            "externalIds": [],
            "access": [],
            "roles": [
              "573511a8ffaa7a0100a5718a"
            ],
            "owner": "57776507ac0a88010063b9b8"
          }
        },
        {
          "position": "FF",
          "name": {
            "_id": "57439d856e67b40100d4c420",
            "modified": "2016-05-24T00:17:09.493Z",
            "data": {
              "userName": "person.two",
              "fullName": "Person Two",
              "emailAddress": "person.two@mysite.com",
              "primaryPhoneNumber": "5555556666",
              "secondaryPhoneNumber": "",
              "assignedStation": "",
              "emtLevel": "b",
              "driving": {
                "d": true
              },
              "group": "suppression"
            },
            "form": "57427ba554ec330100dad645",
            "created": "2016-05-24T00:17:09.474Z",
            "externalIds": [],
            "access": [],
            "roles": [
              "573511a8ffaa7a0100a5718a"
            ],
            "owner": "5734bba2ffaa7a0100a57029"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
```

So the issue is how to take those objects and organize them into the two groupings mentioned above so that I can just loop through them with ngRepeat in my template. What I have so far is this:

```
vm.cellModifier = function(cell) {
  cell.text = 'Test Text';
  var shifts = vm.events;
  // Get the date for the cell.
  this.cellDate = moment(cell.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
 // Iterate over shifts to get ones for this day.
  this.cell = cell;
  this.todayShifts = {};
  shifts.forEach(function(shift, index, allShifts) {
    var shiftDate = moment(shift.data.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    // Now we need to see if this shift belongs to this day.
    if (moment(vm.cellDate).isSame(moment(shiftDate))) {
      // Shift is today, so let's put it into the appropriate array.
      if (typeof vm.todayShifts[shift.data.ampm] == 'undefined') {
        vm.todayShifts[shift.data.ampm] = shift;
      } else {
        vm.todayShifts[shift.data.ampm].push(shift);
      }
    }
  });
  // Add arrays to cell object.
  cell.todayShifts = vm.todayShifts;
};
```

That gives `vm.todayShifts[am]` and `vm.todayShifts[pm]`, but I also would like to get the second level so that I have `vm.todayShifts[am][1]`, `vm.todayShifts[am][2]` etc. Is there an easier way to do what I'm trying to do (I'm fairly certain there is) than adding another section of statements? I'm wondering if a custom directive or component might be cleaner, because then I could just pass my data into that controller, but even then, I would still need to get my data arranged properly so it can be displayed in the proper order.

Hopefully this all makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are actually pretty close... Try this which will always put the data in the format you are asking for.

```
shifts.forEach(function(shift, index, allShifts) {
  var shiftDate = moment(shift.data.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  // Now we need to see if this shift belongs to this day.
  if (moment(vm.cellDate).isSame(moment(shiftDate))) {
    // Shift is today, so let's put it into the appropriate array.
    if (typeof vm.todayShifts[shift.data.ampm] == 'undefined') {

      // Initialize the shifts as an array.
      vm.todayShifts[shift.data.ampm] = [];
    }

    // Push the shift onto the array.
    vm.todayShifts[shift.data.ampm].push(shift);
  }
});
```